# How Can I Evenly Space Input Dropdowns In A TradingView Indicator Settings?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to space an indicator's settings evenly where the dropdown selection of an input populates on the right side regardless of how long the title of the input variable is.

[(Example 1) What I'm trying to mimic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGAd5.png)

Example 1's Code:

```
*length = input.int(13, 'Exponential Moving Average Length', minval=1)  // Alexander Elder, developer of Elder-Ray Inticator, uses the 13-period EMA in order to present the average consensus of price value

dispBbp = input(false, title='Plot as Sum of Bull and Bear Power')
display = input.string('Histogram', 'Display as', options=['Histogram', 'Line', 'Band'])

revBear = input(false, 'Reverse Bear Power Plotting')
smooth = input.int(1, 'Smoothing Length', minval=1)

addIndi = input.string('Colored DMI Line, Alone', 'Add Colored Directional Movement Index, and', options=['Price Convergence/Divergence', 'Least Squares of Price Convergence/Divergence', 'Colored DMI Line, Alone', 'None'])*
```

[(Example 2) My Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM8AA.png)

Example 2 / My code:

```
*signal_mode = input.string(defval='Volume Trends', title='Mode', options=['Volume Trends', 'Momentum Trends', 'Contrarian Trends'], inline='a', group='Base Settings')

signal_sensitivity = input.string(title='Sensitivity', defval='Day Trade', options=['Day Trade', 'Swing Trade'], inline='b', group='Base Settings')
trend_cloud = input(false, title="Trend Cloud", inline='a', group='Overlay Settings')*
```

I can't see anything unique in Example 1's code to enforce this uniformity. Any help is appreciated.

To note: this is in Pine Script V5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **inline=** parameter of the input.*() function forces the dropdown box to join with the title. In your code example, inline= parameter is redundant as only one input is used per each line, the inline= parameter was designed to merge multiple inputs in a single line.

Remove the inline= parameter and the inputs would be aligned on the right side. The width of the inputs menu depends on the longest title:

```
signal_mode = input.string(defval='Volume Trends', title='Mode', options=['Volume Trends', 'Momentum Trends', 'Contrarian Trends'],  group='Base Settings')

signal_sensitivity = input.string(title='Sensitivity', defval='Day Trade', options=['Day Trade', 'Swing Trade'], group='Base Settings')

longTitleInput = input.int(1, 'long title to expand the width of the inputs menu', group='Base Settings')
```

[image]